# Obtaining a certain view in the ListView

Tags: android, listview

I have a `ListView` with 3 items and an `OnItemClickListener`.

How can I get a `View` of the second item?

I need to change the text in the second item when I click on the first item.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        switch (arg2) {
            case 0:
            ((TextView)/*here i need a view of second item*/).setText();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be , 
You can use view.getParent(), in your case arg1.getParent() and then use getChild() which will return an array of child views and use it accordingly.

you can use arg0.getChildAt(position) , this is better than previous solution, if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you can make the `listView` final (shouldn't be a problem), you can reference it from inside the `onItemClick` method and use its `getChildAt` method to get the `TextView` you need.

```
final ListView listView = ...
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            switch (arg2) {
            case 0:
            ((TextView) lv.getChildAt(1)).setText();
    });
```